# Как проверить наличие класса на странице с помощью phpquery?

Tags: php, dom, парсер

Имеется файл index.html который ссылается на три других файла one.html, two.html и three.html. Структура предельно простая. В файлах one и three имеется тег ul с классом list, а в файле two этого класса и тега нет.

Есть еще файл get.php, который парсит эти страницы и проверяет наличие класса .list, и выводится ответ есть этот класс или его нет. Вот код:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$start = microtime(true);

set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'library/'); 
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'phpQuery/'); 

require('config.php');

function __autoload( $className ) {require_once( "$className.php" );}

echo "<br>".date('H:i:s')." Начинаем парсинг ";
echo '<pre>';

$page=file_get_contents('index.html');
$document = phpQuery::newDocument($page);

$links=[];
foreach($document->find('ul li a') as $link){

$links[] = pq($link)->attr('href');
}
print_r($links);

foreach($links as $sublink){
$pageText =new Curl();
$pagenew=$pageText->get_page($sublink);
$cat_page = phpQuery::newDocument($pagenew);
$catlist = [];

foreach($cat_page as $cat_page){
if($item=pq($cat_page)->find('ul.list a')) {
    echo "class is</br>";}else{
    echo "class not is</br>";}
}


}
```

Проблема в том, что в итоге выводится, что класс есть на всех трех страницах, хотя на второй странице его нет. Помогите пожалуйста понять, что не правильно тут? вот что выводится:

```
11:07:22 Начинаем парсинг
Array
(
[0] => one.html
[1] => two.html
[2] => three.html
)
class is
class is
class is
```

Вот содержимое страниц one.html и three.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">    
</head>

<body>
<ul class="list">
    <li><a href="link.html">link</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

и страницы two.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">    
</head>

<body>
    <p>нет класса</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В phpQuery есть функция hasClass. Она поможет определит наличие класса у элемента.

Comment: А как ее применить? в доке не вижу этой функции. Делаю вот так if($item=pq($cat_page)->find('ul')->hasClass('list')), но теперь выдает отсутствие класса везде

Comment: Вот подобный вопрос задавался и ответ должен подойти. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000743/how-to-check-whether-an-id-exists-using-phpquery-length

Comment: Спасибо, но не подошел

Answer (score 1):

Вы приведите страницы `one.html`, `too.html`,`free.html`. А то условие зависит на прямую от содержимого этих страниц, и тыкать пальцем не продуктивно может быть у вас действительно есть где то li с этим классом. В конце концов сделайте `var_dump($item);` после условия что бы увидеть что он выбирает. Скорее всего `find` возвращает пустой массив там где нет элемента, а пустой массив это не `false`.

далее меняем алгоритм следующим образом

```
foreach($cat_page as $cat_page){
     $item=pq($cat_page)->find('ul.list a');
     var_dump($item);
     if($item) {
       echo "class is</br>";
     }else{
       echo "class not is</br>";
     }
}
```

Запускаем скрипт, смотрим на ввывод что нам вернёться в `$item`
Но прежде сходим в phpDocumentation и найдём find метод

```
    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return phpQueryObject|QueryTemplatesSource|QueryTemplatesParse|QueryTemplatesSourceQuery
     */
```

И так мы видим что он возвращает объект а объект это всё таки `true` всегда.

Далее ищем а как же на проверить число элементов в этом объекте.
И тут же натыкаемся на метод `stack`

```
    /**
     * Internal stack iterator.
     *
     * @access private
     */
    public function stack($nodeTypes = null) {
        if (!isset($nodeTypes))
            return $this->elements;
        if (!is_array($nodeTypes))
            $nodeTypes = array($nodeTypes);
        $return = array();
        foreach($this->elements as $node) {
            if (in_array($node->nodeType, $nodeTypes))
                $return[] = $node;
        }
        return $return;
    }
```

Да всё круто модифицируем наш алгоритм

```
 foreach($cat_page as $cat_page){
         $item=pq($cat_page)->find('ul.list a');
         $arrayForCheck = $item->stack();
         if(count($arrayForCheck) > 0) {
           echo "class is</br>";
         }else{
           echo "class not is</br>";
         }
    }
```

но всё равно нужно посмотреть на файлы прежде чем делать какие то там нибыло выводы. И на будущее используйте документацию в исходниках, и сами пишите свою. И не забываем(забиваем) про простые методы дебага:
 1. `var_dump($var);die;` дамп переменной с остановкой скрипта
 2. `var_dump(get_class($var))` получить име класа объекта 
 3. `var_dump(get_class_methods(get_class($var)))` получить доступные методы класса
 4. etc...

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный разбор и замечания, буду разбираться, нехватающие файлы и привел.

Comment: @ZaurK у тебя этот `foreach($cat_page as $cat_page){` лишний так как он по просту переписывает массив $cat_page первым элементом.

Comment: Действительно...и без foreach работает как работало. Я проверил var_dump($item); там объект возвращается. Вот как мне сделать проверку на наличие класса .list на странице, чтобы в зависимости от его наличия или отсутствия определенные действия развивать?

Comment: @ZaurK `var_dump($item->stack())` что выводит?

Comment: Выводит пустой массив array(0) {}

Comment: У всех или всё таки у того документа у которого нет класса @ZaurK

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41609/discussion-between-zaurk-and-naumov).