# Как продолжить цикл?

Tags: php, phpquery

Суть в том, что я паршу ссылки на страниц(цикл 1), потом уже работаю с каждой страницей(цикл 2) в этих страницах я вытаскиваю информацию и сохраняю и ищу с помощью phpQuery:
`$pos = $doc->find('.tabs-body:first')->find('.item');`
И `foreach` циклом прогоняю каждый блок и уже оттуда вытаскиваю нужную мне информацию.
Проблема в том, что иногда `$pos` пустой, но как мне перейти к следущей странице(отвечает цикл 2)?
Загонять все под `if`? Но как пропустить последний блок с еще одним циклом сохранение массива в бд как раз сохраняется в нем инфа из `$pos` набирая новый массив данных?

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем нашел решение для phpQuery как проверить существует ли объект, но теперь отвалилась запись до проверки в бд... Пойду искать новую ошбику.
Кому надо:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538176/470009

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).